# Вопрос связан с выводом текста в telegram боте. Я хочу чтобы бот выводил в 1 сообщение несколько строк, а получается не то что нужно

Tags: python, строки, бот, telebot

```
c = ''
        name = ["Пельмени Caesar Superior; Elite, 700г","Форель Мореслав слабосоленая филе-кусочки, 150г","Туалетная бумага Soffione Premio трехслойная, 8шт","Корейка По-Черкизовски варено-копченая Черкизово, 300г"]

        c = ''
        for i in name:

            c = c + i

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,c)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что получается, а хотелось бы, чтобы каждый продукт выводился в новой строке. Но при этом это было бы одно сообщение.

Answer (score 2):

Для разделения строк используйте `\n`:

```py
names = [
    "Пельмени Caesar Superior; Elite, 700г",
    "Форель Мореслав слабосоленая филе-кусочки, 150г",
    "Туалетная бумага Soffione Premio трехслойная, 8шт",
    "Корейка По-Черкизовски варено-копченая Черкизово, 300г"
]

text = "\n".join(names)

bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text)
```